# Bash can't find python library but pydev can

Tags: python, module, pydev

I am trying to write some script using Python DNS library (dnspython). I installed it (python-dns and python-dnspython) using packet manager (apt-get install).

I was trying to write the script interactively on the shell, but it keeps saying that it can't find the library.

```
>>> import dns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dns
```

The funny part is, when I make the same import on Eclipse (pydev) it has no problem placing it.
It must be something I do wrong, like not defining the path etc (although this one isn't very likely, since -as far as I know- apt-get is supposed to handle it automatically).

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Python version: 2.7.3

I am a beginner on Linux and on Python (bad combination, I know). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
dpkg -L python-dnspython
```

This gives a long list of paths to where it is installed
On my system python-dnspython is in /usr/share/pyshared/ which (surely) should be in the search path for python.  To be sure, set it manually with

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/pyshared
```

Before running the cli python

Answer (score 2):

Try this in both environments to see what the difference is:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```